# AWS dynamodb create table with "on-demand" ProvisionedThroughput

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

How can I create a DynamoDB table using the Node SDK and specify "on-demand" as the `ProvisionedThroughput`? I get this error when I leave out the `ProvisionedThroughput` option:

```
ValidationException: One or more parameter values were invalid: ReadCapacityUnits and WriteCapacityUnits must both be specified when BillingMode is PROVISIONED
    at Request.extractError (/Users/james/projects/ears/server/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:51:27)
    at Request.callListeners (/Users/james/projects/ears/server/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (/Users/james/projects/ears/server/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (/Users/james/projects/ears/server/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)
    at Request.transition (/Users/james/projects/ears/server/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/Users/james/projects/ears/server/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /Users/james/projects/ears/server/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/james/projects/ears/server/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/james/projects/ears/server/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)
    at Request.callListeners (/Users/james/projects/ears/server/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)
    at Request.emit (/Users/james/projects/ears/server/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (/Users/james/projects/ears/server/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)
    at Request.transition (/Users/james/projects/ears/server/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/Users/james/projects/ears/server/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /Users/james/projects/ears/server/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/james/projects/ears/server/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
```

Here is my code that attempts to create the table:

```
await dynamodb
  .createTable({
    TableName: `${studyName}StudyCodeDB`,
    AttributeDefinitions: [
      {
        AttributeName: 'studyCode',
        AttributeType: 'S',
      },
      {
        AttributeName: 'studyCodeCreationDate',
        AttributeType: 'N',
      },
    ],
    KeySchema: [
      {
        AttributeName: 'studyCode',
        KeyType: 'HASH',
      },
      {
        AttributeName: 'studyCodeCreationDate',
        KeyType: 'RANGE',
      },
    ],
  })
  .promise();
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to set `BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST` which is for on-demand throughput. Otherwise by default it's set to `PROVISIONED` ([documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-dynamodb-table.html#cfn-dynamodb-table-billingmode)).

Your code should look like this:

```
await dynamodb
  .createTable({
    TableName: `${studyName}StudyCodeDB`,
    BillingMode: 'PAY_PER_REQUEST',
    AttributeDefinitions: [
      {
        AttributeName: 'studyCode',
        AttributeType: 'S',
      },
      {
        AttributeName: 'studyCodeCreationDate',
        AttributeType: 'N',
      },
    ],
    KeySchema: [
      {
        AttributeName: 'studyCode',
        KeyType: 'HASH',
      },
      {
        AttributeName: 'studyCodeCreationDate',
        KeyType: 'RANGE',
      },
    ],
  })
  .promise();
```